# How to serve Wordpress folder over subdomain?

Tags: php, htaccess, subdomains

I have wordpress website `www.example.com` I have one subdomain whose folder is also created in `public_html` which is same as wordpress installation folder.

What I'm looking for is if someone use `apps.example.com` the site `www.example.com/apps/` should be served on the subdomain.

Site is hosted on shared hosting, How can I achive this?

Example scenario:

What user will see `apps.example.com/android/`

Page will be served `www.example.com/apps/android`

Comment: This is normally something you can do from the hosting control panel, but that differs between hosts and ultimately has nothing to do with WordPress. You should ask your host.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, as there isn't really anything special you need to do to serve a WordPress installation from a subdomain? Or are you wanting to move the WordPress installation from the main domain to the subdomain? Or internally route requests for the subdomain to the main domain (but then why install WP on the main domain in the first place)?